# Connecting to ATEN KVM-over-IP from a modern environment

Tags: internet-explorer, datacenter, keyboard-video-mouse

We have several [KN4132v](https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/kvm/kvm-over-ip-switches/kn4132v/) and KN2140v appliances connected to multiple servers in our lab. These are multi-thousand dollar devices that I would be hard-pressed to justify throwing away.

Unfortunately, the only way we have for connecting to them is through an [ATEN CC2000](https://www.aten.com/us/en/products/kvm/management-software--control-center/cc2000/) system that only supports Internet Explorer running an old version of Java. It stopped working on my Windows laptop at some point, and I have not been able to get it working again.

Is there any way to connect to these things without using a Java applet, preferably from Linux?

**EDIT:** I resorted to downloading a [VirtualBox image from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), and installing Java 7 from the [Java Download Archive](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html). Also had to set Java security to low. I feel dirty.

Comment: Did you update their firmware?

Comment: @Michael Yes. However, the devices' firmware doesn't seem to have anything to do with the way the CC2000 interface works.